# Как расскрасить отрезки графика разными цветами из списка значений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, визуализация

Есть данные для графика:

```
p = [10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10]
```

И есть другие данные:

```
s = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Где: `p` это график для `plt.plot(p)`, а значения `s` - это раскраска для него разными цветами. Причём в `s` могут быть и другие значения, например 5 или 6 и т.п. - они всегда будут разными цветами.

Как расскрасить график по `s`?

Comment: не совсем понятна суть вопроса - вы хотите получить __отрезки__ заданных цветов или __точки__ заданных цветов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

uniq_colors = set(s)
n = len(uniq_colors)
x = np.arange(len(p))
p = np.array(p)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(19, 3))
colors = {i:c for i,c in zip(uniq_colors, cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,n)))}
for i in range(1, len(p)):
    ax.plot(x[i-1:i+1], p[i-1:i+1], c=colors[s[i]])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @nik_golunov, `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(19, 3))`